# Convert session from PHP to NodeJS - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, node.js, session

I am trying to convert a PHP session to a NodeJS session by passing the variables via JSON data, but I'm getting an error. Is there any other any to share a session between PHP and NodeJS? PHP contains the session and Node will get the session from PHP.

This is php page output: `{"id":"1","username":"jon"}`

Getting this error: `Unexpected end of JSON input`

**My PHP**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$respose["session"]=array();
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) 
 {


 $respose["session"] = array(           
          'id'=> $_SESSION['id'],
          'username'=> $_SESSION['username']
        );

   echo json_encode($respose["session"]);

 }

 ?>
```

**My NodeJS**

```
      http.get("http://localhost/sapapplication/php_application/php/
session_node.php", res => {
        const { statusCode } = res;
        const contentType = res.headers["content-type"];

        let error;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
            error = new Error("Request Failed.\n" + `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
        } 
        if (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            // consume response data to free up memory
            res.resume();
            return;
        }
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
            let rawData = "";
            res.on("data", chunk => {
                rawData += chunk;
                console.error('--->',chunk);
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                try {
                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    req.session.user = parsedData;
                    resp.json(parsedData);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e.message);
                }
            });
    }).on("error", e => {
        console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
        next(e);
    });
```

Comment: The error you're getting is probably from the fact that $_SESSION['userid'] is likely not set for Node.JS's session.  Since it's not set, you don't output anything, and thus get that error.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail on what you're trying to do? Are you trying to pass a user's session information to Node.JS?  Or is Node.JS logging into and managing it's own session?

Comment: I just realized that response may sound confusing if you don't have this bit of information: The reason I ask is that the session is (usually) identified by a cookie. Since Node.JS's request mechanism doesn't have the user's cookie, it doesn't get the same response as the browser would. Unless, of course Node.JS is the client itself.  Having more info on what you're trying to do will probably get you better answers.

Comment: i am trying to use php session in node js.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, `$_SESSION['userid']` is not set for the `Node.JS` request so you are getting that error because your endpoint doesn't produce any output in that case. The reason for this is that your session ID cookie is set in your browser, and so would not be sent in the `Node.JS` request. `Node.JS` in this instance *can't* get the session by itself because it doesn't have that ID.

There are a few different scenarios that come to mind.  I'm not exactly sure which (if any) would fit your case, and I'm not super familiar with node, so these will be more or less broad overviews:

**Scenario 1)** node and PHP are on the same domain and both accessed with a browser. (either via AJAX or normal pages.)

If you're accessing your `Node.JS` instance with your browser and it's on the same origin as your PHP scripts, you could take the session ID cookie your browser is likely already passing, and then include that in your nodejs HTTP request. (Unfortunately, I don't know enough about node to provide much on how to do this. I'd assume cookies npm package would be useful.)  Once you have the session ID from the browser's cookie, you can include it in your node requests and PHP should respond the way you're expecting.

**Scenario 2)** node is accessed by the browser (AJAX or full pages), but is on a different domain

In this scenario, you'd either pass the pertinent data with every request, OR try to get a session ID set in the browser that you could then use in your node http request.  I think the former is easier myself. However, syncing the session ID between the two shouldn't be impossible. You'd basically send the session ID to node (perhaps via query string or with a special on-page POST request) and have node set a similar cookie for it's domain, which you can then pass in your HTTP requests. Note: You'd have to make sure they stayed in sync.

**Scenario 3)** node is a backend service NOT directly accessed by the browser

In this instance, it would be a lot easier to just have PHP make requests to node with the necessary session information, and basically use node as a RESTful API service.

**Scenario 4)** node is a backend service NOT directly accessed by the browser, but the node processes run long so you can't feasibly wait for a response from node

If the processes run by node are long-running ones (i.e. you can't wait for a full response in the PHP), you could use node the same way as scenario 3, and use this theoretical API to queue a job and return a job ID. Record the session information in your queue for the job and process the queue in the background. Use the job ID to keep track of it.